# if x matches y webscraping selenium

Tags: python, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm scraping a website and
I want to check if the content that is found by `browser.find_element()` matches a specific word given in the code. If it does, it should do thing 1; if it doesn't, it should do thing 2.

```
Check = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 'XPATH')
if Check == 'Target':
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 'XPATH')
```

Above will return an object of WebElement. If you want to store the content of an HTML node into a variable, you need to use `.text`. Check the code below:

```
Check = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 'XPATH').text
```

**Example:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

Check = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='-img _glyph']").text
if Check == 'Stack Overflow':
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to check if the text in the element equals `"target"` then you could use:

```
check = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "XPATH")
if check.text == "Target":
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: The `if check` portion isn't necessary because the first line with throw an ElementNotFoundException if the element isn't found. I would instead use `.find_elements()` (plural) in the first line to better handle potential exceptions.